# How to output negative java.math.BigInteger 64 bit numbers for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, biginteger

How do I configure  java.math.BigInteger to output in the decimal format supported by Redshift BigInteger so I can ingest it through the COPY command? I have a 64 bit number that is not outputting as a negative integer when the 64 bit is set.

Comment: This is very confusing. "I have a 64 bit number that is not outputting as a negative integer when the 64 bit is set."
Well, I don't know what that means since you have shown any "outputting" code at all.

Comment: I was using toString() method as output format which was why there was confusion in my results. Based on responses if using the longValue() method this issue goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on feedback... this will work with 64 bit numbers

```
public String toString(BigInteger bigInteger){
        String result;

        result = Long.toString(bigInteger.longValue());

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Then reform your question as a question, and copy the answer in to your answer.

Comment: Are you aware of `BigInteger.longValue()` ?

Comment: Your way to do this is extremely inefficient. If you want to flip all bits, then use `BigInteger.xor()`. But you don't need to: just use `BigInteger.longValue()`. That is very efficient and will return negative and positive 64 bit values in two's complement.